# Validators on deployment server stopped working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0, validation

This is strange and baffling. In my ASP.NET 2.0 app I have a form that uses a number of client-side validators. Custom, Regularexpression and RequiredField. My app requires that I enable or disable certain validators based on a dropdown selection. I do this in my codebehind event. All this works great in my dev environment however when I deploy to the server it does not. Mainly when I run the app from the server it will not allow me to enable or disable the validators in code. When I set the enabled property in the aspx file it remains in that state regardless of what I do in the server event. Again - this works perfectly in dev. Any suggestions? Could it be the version of .NET 2.0 is different on my dev machine and the server? I am at a loss and we are heading for production soon. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a .NET version issue. Once I applied the 2.0 Service Pack 2 on the server my problems went away.

Answer (score 0):

Do the validators work at all on the production machine? That is, do they prevent you from entering invalid data?

I have a vague recollection of something like this happening to me. It may have been an issue of the JavaScript file needed by the validators not being sent from the server. Do a View Source, or turn on debugging (FireBug or IE8's F12 command). See if you're maybe getting JavaScript errors you didn't know about.

Comment: The validators work when enabled from the start (that is in the aspx page). However I cannot disable them or enable them if they are set to enabled in the aspx page. My app requires this as different controls are enabled based on dropdown selection.

Comment: Ok, then this is not the problem I recall.